# Please help me in finding the distinct row

Tags: sql, oracle

```
**P_NO       N_ADD           O_ADD            DATE_CHANGED**
*12646                  abc@gmail.com   02-JAN-15 10.17.52.000000000 AM*
12646   abc@gmail.com   test@gmail.com  02-JAN-15 10.15.52.000000000 AM
12646   abc@gmail.com                   02-JAN-15 10.15.52.000000000 AM
12646                   abc@gmail.com   02-JAN-15 10.13.25.000000000 AM
12646   abc@gmail.com   abc@gmail.com   02-JAN-15 10.13.25.000000000 AM

*12648                  test@gmail.com  24-FEB-15 01.46.46.000000000 PM*
12648   test@gmail.com  test@gmail.com  09-JAN-15 09.21.31.000000000 AM
12648   test@gmail.com  test@gmail.com  09-JAN-15 09.21.31.000000000 AM
12648   test@gmail.com  test@gmail.com  09-JAN-15 09.21.31.000000000 AM
12648   test@gmail.com  test@gmail.com  09-JAN-15 09.20.51.000000000 AM
12648   test@gmail.com  test@gmail.com  09-JAN-15 09.20.51.000000000 AM
12648   test@gmail.com  test@gmail.com  09-JAN-15 09.20.51.000000000 AM
12648   test@gmail.com  test@gmail.com  09-JAN-15 09.20.09.000000000 AM
12648   test@gmail.com  abc@gmail.com   09-JAN-15 09.20.09.000000000 AM
```

This is the structure what i got from below query.

```
select * 
from test1 
where O_ADD is not null 
order by P_NO asc,DATE_CHANGED desc.
```

Here i want only the 1st row which is recent and with N_ADD is null for every distinct P_NO. Like below.

```
**P_NO  N_ADD        O_ADD              DATE_CHANGED**
12646            abc@gmail.com      02-JAN-15 10.17.52.000000000 AM
12648            test@gmail.com     24-FEB-15 01.46.46.000000000 PM
```

could anyone please help me with this query.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want the complete row, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p_no order by date_changed) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where n_add is null and seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT P_NO, N_ADD, O_ADD, MAX(DATE_CHANGED)
FROM YOUR_TAB
WHERE N_ADD IS NULL
GROUP BY P_NO, N_ADD, O_ADD;
```